# Где в реестре хранится информация об USB save POWER

Tags: реестр

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где хранится в реестре информация об этой галочке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s.

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}ID\HcDisableSelectiveSuspend
```

не она, меняю не изменяет.

Для карты прекрасно поменяло в

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}ID\PnPCapabilities
```

Всем юсбихам выключить к сожалению не выход, принципиально, чтобы снялась галочка именно на одном хабе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый метод был верным

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}\ID\HcDisableSelectiveSuspend 1
```

Оказалось, что USB root HUB меняет HcDisableSelectiveSuspend  у айди, который закреплен за Intel(R), который виднеется на скрине(т.к. у них одинаковый драйвер).

Выяснялось методом экспортирования ветки реестра {36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000} до и после постановки галочки.
После этого 2 файла сравнивались в командной строке

```
fc первыйфайл.reg второйфайл.reg > результат.txt
```